# scrolling a large image on android

Tags: android, image, scroll

Suppose you have a large image that extends beyond the borders of the android phone screen and you need to scroll it around using touch. Im not sure how to start coding for it. Any tips and hints would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use a ScrollView as your base Layout. The ScrollView could then wrap the single ImageView. ScrollView is meant to only contain a single Layout inside it, so if you have more than just the ImageView such as ImageView with TextView you will have to wrap these two items in another ViewGroup such as LinearLayout or RelativeLayout, etc.

Comment: The ScrollView is only going to be particularly useful for images whose height exceeds the bounds of the screen. IMHO i would probably downsize my images and use a zoom animation to view them larger to avoid out of memory errors. See this tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html and also http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html for displaying bitmaps efficiently.